# Too many TimerQueueTimer objects getting allocated and consuming high memory

Tags: memory-leaks, timer

I have a Web API running that connects with a Service Bus to write messages to Topics and deployed in Service Fabric. I see unusually high memory usage and most of the memory is consumed by TimerQueueTimer objects, although I have not explicitly initialized any Timer.

[image]

When I trace back to see how these timers are created, I see below namespaces:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryModules.<Modules>k__BackingField ->
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.SnapshottingList<Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryModule>.Collection ->
System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryModule>._items ->
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryModule[16] at [4] ->
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule.timer ->
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.Implementation.Timer.Timer.timer ->
System.Threading.Timer.m_timer

--------------------------------------------

Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.TopicClient.<ServiceBusConnection>k__BackingField ->
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnection.<ConnectionManager>k__BackingField ->
Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject<Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpConnection>.taskCompletionSource ->
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpConnection>.m_task ->
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpConnection>.m_result ->
Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpConnection.heartBeat ->
Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpConnection+HeartBeat+TimedHeartBeat.heartBeatTimer ->
System.Threading.Timer.m_timer ->
System.Threading.TimerHolder.m_timer ->
System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.m_next ->

--------------------------------------------

Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.CommunicationClientCache<ServiceClient.HttpCommunicationClient>.cacheCleanupTimer ->
System.Threading.Timer.m_timer ->
System.Threading.TimerHolder.m_timer
```

Not sure why these timers are never collected and all of these are lying in Gen2. Over a period the memory spikes and the application becomes unresponsive. Any leads to when such Timer objects are never collected?

Comment: out of curiosity what tool did you use to get the report?

Comment: I used JetBrains DotMemory

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue (Used the same tool to investigate). Did you find any clue on what causing the problem ?

Comment: Not yet.. Different tools are showing differently. I tried ANTS memory profiler and it shows Timer objects are only 9MB in size. Even WinDBG shows 9MB in size. So Timers are not an issue in my case. Use WinDBG's "dumpheap -stat" command to check for the largest consuming objects. Also we found too many dynamic modules loaded repeatedly in our code. Suspecting that might be the issue. Still analysing.

Comment: @vrcks, did you ever have an update on this? I'm faced with the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We were seeing a similar issue recently, primarily with `TimerQueueTimer` and Application Insights.

We upgraded `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` from 2.3.0 to 2.8.2 and that seems to have resolved the issue. Most likely it was [#690](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/690), fixed in v2.4.0.